# Can't read data from services using subscribe function

Tags: angular, subscribe

In the parent to `setData`:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.updateData(this.temp)
}
updateData(value: Employee) {
   this.parentData.setData(value)
}
```

In the child to `getData`:

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private parentData:GetParentData){
    setTimeout(
        console.log("Heavy:" , this.parentData.tempdata.subscribe(data=>console.log("Jessi:",data))),
        this.parentData.getData().subscribe(data=>alert("hi"))
        ,3000)
}
```

The service:

```
export class GetParentData{
private dataObs$ = new Subject<Employee>();
tempdata = this.dataObs$.asObservable();
getData():Observable<Employee>{
    return this.tempdata;
}
setData(data: Employee) {
    this.dataObs$.next(data);
}
```

The console response is:

> Heavy:
>   Subscriber {closed: false, syncErrorValue: null, syncErrorThrown: false, syncErrorThrowable: false, isStopped: false…}closed: falsedestination: SafeSubscriberisStopped: falsesyncErrorThrowable: falsesyncErrorThrown: falsesyncErrorValue: null_subscriptions: Array(1)**proto**: Subscription

Comment: Well what did you expect? The result of subscribing *is a subscription*.

Answer (score 1):

Since `.subscribe()` returns a Subscription, `console.log` printed what you asked it to print: the Subscription itself. There are a few ways you could get the data and print it to the console.

If printing is all you want to do, I would get the Subscription out of the first console.log, and move the code to a separate function since `setTimeout` only takes one function.

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute, private parentData:GetParentData){
    setTimeout(this.printData(), 3000);
}

printData(): void{
    this.parentData.tempdata.subscribe(data=>console.log("Heavy:" ,"Jessi:",data)));
    this.parentData.getData().subscribe(data=>alert("hi"));
}
```

I assume your alert function was for testing, it wouldn't need to stay in `printData()`.

Comment: How would we pull data from the subscribe function and use it elsewhere? Say I want to get the `data` from the `.subscribe()` method and use `data` within another function? All the examples all over the place show the old RXJS syntax - so confusing.